# I currently have no source.list directory or file due to too many failed to fetch errors, how can I resolve?

Tags: ubuntu

I am lacking experience in this area, but I was prompted to make changes to the source.list as Digital Ocean no longer supported, I was experiencing way too many failed to fetch errors, I followed an article advising me to go to default source.list by using rm source.list command.  Now Im not sure what to do from here, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which Ubuntu version you have?

Comment: it might help to share... what changes you made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/sources.list` is the list of [repositories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_repository) which [package managers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager) ([apt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT_(software)), [Synapctic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synaptic_(software)) etc.) of [Debian](https://www.debian.org) and its derivatives ([Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/), [Linux Mint](https://linuxmint.com) etc.). As you've deleted the list, the package managers don't work.

`Failed to fetch` means simply that package manager wasn't able to retrieve the packages you tried to install. There can be multiple reasons. Since `sources.list` is as described above, deleting it (command `rm` = remove) definitely won't fix these errors.

To verify which Ubuntu version you have, open terminal and give command `lsb_release -a`. You see and output like this:

```
Distribution ID: Ubuntu
Description:     Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:         22.04
Codename:        jammy
```

According to [r/ubuntu](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/ukj7og/complete_sourceslist_file_for_ubuntu_2204_lts/) below is the complete `sources.list` of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. If the output you see matches exactly what's above, you can simply give command `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`, copy the text below, paste to `nano` and save the file. If you're not familiar with `nano`, you can also use any other text editor like [Gedit](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit) (Ubuntu's default graphical editor) to create the file, as long as you run it as `root` and you save it as `sources.list` to `/etc/apt`.

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-security main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ jammy partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ jammy partner
```

If `lsb_release -a` output doesn't match exactly, go to [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) SE site and ask for default `sources.list` that matches the output.

In the future: do **NOT** delete files haphazardly. If the advice on a website tells you to do so, *FIRST* copy the file to another name - for example in this case

`sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.orig`

and *THEN* delete the original file. If things go wrong, you can then simply restore the original file with

`sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list.orig /etc/apt/sources.list`.

This applies also to modifying files - always keep a copy of the original unmodified file. Easiest is just to keep it in the original directory with a descriptive name.

Also, if the website really advised you to delete your `sources.list`, I recommend you at least first verify with another source like Ask Ubuntu that the advice is correct before following advice from that site.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies, I was using the focal release.
Managed to eventually fix and upgrade to latest version (Jammy).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).